# Looking for an element in the array scala

Tags: arrays, scala, missing-data

I'm writing this function in order to identify the first missing element from the array.
I want to return the missing element but I'm getting a Unit

I can't identify what am I missing

```
def missingElement(a : Array[Int]) : Int = {

  val result =for (i <- 1 to a.length) {
    if(! a.contains(i)) {
      i
    } 
  }
  result

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"identify the first" is a `find` operation, so the code might look like this:

```
def missingElement(a: Array[Int]): Option[Int] = 
  a.indices.find(i => !a.contains(i+1))
```

This returns an `Option` because there might not be a missing element, in which case it will return `None`, otherwise it will return `Some(n)`.

Comment: this is an out of context question, but is there a way to measure time and space complexity in scala?

Comment: There is no automatic way. A starting point is [this article](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) which gives the complexity of various operations on the main collection types in the standard library.